# How to share an instance among several classes in c++, not using Singleton pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

Now I'm developing a c++ application and I'm facing a problem of sharing an instance.

For this problem, I created a simple class diagram. I want to share HogeDataManager for class A and C. A creates HogeDataManager and read HogeData via its public methods. And B adds some data to HogeDataManager.

For sharing HogeDataManager, I have to prepare set_mgr method for B and C. But I think it is not a smart way. Of course if I adopt Singleton pattern, it will be resolved. But Singleton is sometimes dangerous, so I want to find better ways to avoid such a problem.

[image]

Comment: _"For sharing HogeDataManager, I have to prepare set_mgr method"_ It's better to require this parameter in the constructors of these classes.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you avoid singleton?

Comment: You should revise the scenario of using `HogeDataManager`, its lifetime, possible number of instances, contexts, states. This will help you to make a better decision.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is good:
A creates HogeDataManager, and takes it over to B, and B to C.
only missing yet the decision, which Object A, B or C has the responsibility, to destruct HogeDataManager finally.
If you deside, that A must create and destruct HogeDataManager, then you need a unset_mgr() in B and C.